# escaping single and double backslash from json

Tags: python, json, escaping

I am trying to read a windows path encoded in a json string.
The path is something like

```
\\sys\tld\a\b\c
```

The following works:

```
import json
json.loads('{"mypath" : "\\\\b\\\\a" }')

[Out] {'mypath': '\\b\\a'}.
```

However, my path does not have a double backslahs before `a`

The following does not work (2 and 3 backslashes respectively):

```
json.loads('{"mypath" : "\\\\b\\a" }')
JSONDecodeError: Invalid \escape: line 1 column 17 (char 16)


json.loads('{"mypath" : "\\\\b\\\a" }')
JSONDecodeError: Invalid \escape: line 1 column 17 (char 16)


json.loads('{"mypath" : r"\b\a" }')
JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 13 (char 12)
```

How should I encode my path (\sys\tld\a\b\c) to be read correctly from a json text file?

Comment: Have you tried putting `r` in front? This denotes a raw string. Try this `r'\b\a'`

Comment: Does not work. I will add to the example.

Comment: Maybe this can help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48415928/how-to-deal-with-json-and-windows-paths-in-python

Comment: That's because `\` has to be escaped both for the Python string literal *and* the JSON string literal contained in the Python string.

Comment: could you propose a solution?

Comment: In most cases, you can use a platform-agnostic path with forward slashes, and the function using the path will parse it correctly for use on Windows. Just use `//sys/tld/a/b/c`.

Comment: @OrestisZekai A raw string literal cannot end with a backslash, since `\'` will always be treated as a literal single quote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that in a JSON string literal, a backslash has to be escaped to produce a literal `\`. However, you then need to escape all of *those* backslashes in your Python string literal to create the correct JSON string value.

```
>>> json.dumps("\\")  # A string consisting of a single backslash
'"\\\\"'
```

In your exact case, a properly encoded version of the path would be

```
>>> json.dumps({'mypath': r'\\sys\tld\a\b\c'})
'{"mypath": "\\\\\\\\sys\\\\tld\\\\a\\\\b\\\\c"}'
```

That looks like a lot of backslashes, but most of them are added by `str.__repr__` for display purposes, not part of the actual value.

```
>>> print(json.dumps({'mypath': r'\\sys\tld\a\b\c'}))
{"mypath": "\\\\sys\\tld\\a\\b\\c"}
```

Each backslash in the original path corresponds to two backslashes in the JSON-encoded string.

---

Using a raw string literal prevents you from having to escape each backslash again in the literal:

```
>>> '\\\\sys\\tld\\a\\b\\c'
'\\\\sys\\tld\\a\\b\\c'
>>> r'\\sys\tld\a\b\c'
'\\\\sys\\tld\\a\\b\\c'
```

However, a raw string literal cannot *end* with a backslash, meaning you'll have to at least rely on string literal concatenation to append a backslash to a raw string literal.

```
>>> '\\foo\\'
'\\foo\\'
>>> r'\foo''\\'
'\\foo\\'
```

---

In the end, though, it's simplest to avoid Windows-style file paths altogether. At the very least, Python built-in functions like `open` will parse POSIX-style paths correctly, even on Windows.

```
# Open \\sys\tld\a\b\c
with open('//sys/tld/a/b/c') as f:
    ...
```