# Python - How to write a windows path to a json file?

Tags: python

I am working together with a colleague and he has Ubuntu while I have windows. We have a dataset of json files which have in them a "path" written. His paths look like this:

```
'C:/Users/krock/Desktop/FIIT/BP/Ubuntu/luadb/etc/luarocks_test/modules/30log/share/lua/5.3/30log.lua'
```

But this doesn't work on Windows, I was trying to do

```
some_string.replace('/', '\\')
```

But this results in strings written in json that look like this:

```
'C:\\Users\\krock\\Desktop\\FIIT\\BP\\Ubuntu\\luadb\\etc\\luarocks_test\\data_all'
```

On my windows machine, I can't read (the program) these paths as it give an error:

> No such file or directory

Is there a solution to this?

EDIT: I tried using Path from pathlib, but I got another error saying:

> TypeError: Object of type WindowsPath is not JSON serializable

I found the solution to this is to do str(Path(path_string)), but the result is again the path in double quotes.

Comment: Have you seen this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48415928/how-to-deal-with-json-and-windows-paths-in-python). '/' is a valid separator.

Comment: Also, just being a rubber duck here, one, are you sure the path actually exists? Can you navigate to the path in Explorer? Also, why are you trying to store (absolute) paths in JSON?

Comment: This actually works now, but I am almost sure it didn't before. '/' does work now.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the solution is to use Python's built in pathlib. Also, using string literals might help the clarity of your program.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html

Comment: Updated post after trying Path().

Comment: I think the best way to unify both systems, and also save path info to a json, would be to save your path names as posix paths. Python's pathlib is smart enough to pick up on everything, so on windows you can load a posix style path in just fine. The pathlib module was created for just this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

This question is missing code samples, so can't be more specific, but generally speaking, doing this manually is error-prone. Consider using a library, such as [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path). E.G:

```
>>> from pathlib import Path
>>> Path('luarocks_test/modules/30log/share/lua/5.3/30log.lua')
PosixPath('luarocks_test/modules/30log/share/lua/5.3/30log.lua')
```

On Windows, instantiating a Path would give you a WindowsPath. You'll also want to use relative, rather than absolute references, as the paths will be different on your workstations.

Comment: Updated post after trying Path().

Comment: This is why you should provide code that demonstrates your problem. Please provide a code example and we'll be better able to help. The answer provided by @xinkecf35 above might help.